# Converting a Ceiling Fan into a normal light fixture, light switch box is confounding me!

Tags: electrical

hoping someone can help me here as I'm totally confused. I'm replacing my kid's ceiling fan with a light fixture and that was straight forward. The problem I'm having is the lightswitch which was basically a plate that held a remote control to control the fan.

It's wired to always be on and controlled by the remote, when I opened it up there were 3 sets of wires, I undid them and tried a few configurations but can't find the magic combination that works, some of them tripping the breaker.

Help?[image]

Answer (score 5):

We occasionally see people disconnect all the wires from each other and spread them out for a photo-op.  *What do you expect us to see, that you do not?*

Except the "bird on a wire" motif, so "A" for composition!

The information you're looking for, "how all this is hooked up", was stored in *how the wires were connected before*. Unfortunately you  destroyed it, by staging this photo.

That's why never to do that.

And no more experimenting without experienced advice. There are lots of combinations which will "work" *and then kill you*.  Like the lack of a third ground wire is a raven.  I hope the hot cable back to the panel has a good ground!

### However you might have gotten lucky.

More likely than not, this is a very common "power into the box and onward to other locations, with a spur to the lamp".  If so this is pretty straightforward - let's hope so.

First, how many breakers do you need to turn off to get every single wire de-energized, including the whites?  If more than one, then we're done here, it's time to hire an electrician or competent handyman who can do the field testing we can't walk you through.  If 1 breaker, we have a shot.

You will need a black and bare pigtail wire.  Turn off the breaker for all wire changes.  Still, handle the wires as if live.

Grounds: Connect all bare wires to each other and to a pigtail.  That will ground the switch.  4 grounds = best a red or tan wire nut. Crank it down "gorilla-tight" not "monkey tight", really.  Push all the grounds but the pigtail into the back of the box. We're done with them.

Neutrals: Connect all white wires to each other. Again, wire nut gorilla-tight (yellow or red will do).  Now, go turn the breaker back on.  Does it trip instantly?  If yes, you did not get lucky.  You need that semi-professional to do lots of field testing and tracing.

If no breaker trip, turn it off manually and continue. Push the neutrals into the back of the box. We're done with them.

### Figuring out the hots

Search the house for everything else that has lost power. Make it so you can tell if they regain power. Also, if you haven't installed the ceiling fixture, do so.

Turn off the breaker. Pick any 2 black wires.  (yes, we're experimenting, but in a controlled way). If exactly one tests as "hot", make sure that's one of them.  Connect them to each other.  Loosely is fine, no need to crank down the wire nut like you mean it.  Leave the other capped and turn the breaker on. What happens?

- Breaker trip (unlikely) = this is beyond anything people on the internet can help with. Go directly to professional.  Do not pass "go". Do not collect $200. (More the opposite, sadly).
- The lamp turns on, and refuses to turn off. (don't sweat it)
- The other stuff in other rooms that was broken, is now working.  Grats, you hit the winner.  These are all wires that are supposed to be "always-hot".
- Nothing at all.

If you didn't get the winner, try another black-black pair.  The tests-as-hot wire needs to be one.

Once you find the winner, add a black pigtail and crank it down gorilla-tight in a yellow or red wire-nut.

Now you have 3 wires not resolved. 2 pigtails and a lone black wire. Feeling like you're in the homestretch? You are.  Attach to the switch, done!

"If you don't know the bare wire goes to the green screw, I will poop in your box" says the bird.

Comment: Seriously. If this electrician thing doesn't work for you, start writing books!

Answer (score 3):

As usual, Harper created a great answer, with great step-by-step instructions. There is only one more item to add:

#### How to Handle Smart Switch/Dimmer/etc.

If you are using an ordinary "dumb" switch - a simple toggle (or the Decora equivalent) then Harper's instructions are all you need.

However, there are two possible complications:

- Line/Hot vs. Load/Switched Hot

An ordinary switch does not care, in any way, which screw gets connected to the hot wire (always on) vs. the switched hot wire (on when the switch is flipped). But many smart switches, dimmers, motion detectors, lighted switches, etc. do care. The Line/Hot (terminology varies by manufacturer) connection on the switch connects to the pigtail of "pair of blacks + a pigtail". The Load/Switched Hot connection on the switch connects to the single black wire.

- Neutral

An ordinary switch does not need a neutral connections. Many, but not all, smart switches and other fancier switches require a neutral. In fact, recent code requires neutral in (most) switch boxes but older houses don't have that - consider yourself lucky. If you need neutral for the switch, add a white pigtail to the 3 white wires and connect the other end to the switch.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking the time to answer my question Harper and manassehkatz, I really appreciate it and I am a total idiot for not taking a "before" photo before messing with the wires but appreciate the complement on my composition. ;)

I *think* this is a solvable issue? I'm able to follow through Harper's steps most of the way, it's all on one breaker and doesn't trip if I hook up everything and the other lights on the breaker are "on".

Comment: Ops sorry, accidentally submitted my reply before properly edited!

The new lamp where the ceiling fan is off with the wiring that allows the other lights to be on again but when I hook everything up to a norma decora light switch, it will all be on until I flick the switch, which flips the breaker. :( 

Assuming it's related to the light switch and how it's wired per manassehkatz's comment? It's a not-lighted decora so it seems like that would be an "ordinary" switch....

Comment: 1 - Picture of how things are connected now? 2 - What colors are the wires going to the new switch?